# Want to Remove Validation in Resume Upload in in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, resume

We are working on Job Scrip. Faces problem in signup page validation. It has on Resume as well. We need to remove the Validation from Upload Resume. How to remove the Validation from the Signup page at upload Resume only. Please help us in this.

Controller is in codeigniter. Help us, we for stuck into this.

```
    $this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique', 'The %s is already taken');

    if (empty($_FILES['cv_file']['name']))
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cv_file', 'Resume', 'required');

    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="errowbox"><div class="erormsg">', '</div></div>');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
        $data['cpt_code'] = create_ml_captcha();
        $this->load->view('jobseeker_signup_view',$data);
        return;

    }
    $current_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $job_seeker_array = array(
                            'first_name' => $this->input->post('full_name'),
                            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                            'password' => $this->input->post('pass'),
                            'dob' => $this->input->post('dob_year').'-'.$this->input->post('dob_month').'-'.$this->input->post('dob_day'),
                            'mobile' => $this->input->post('mobile_number'),
                            'home_phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
                            'present_address' => $this->input->post('current_address'),
                            'country' => $this->input->post('country'),
                            'city' => $this->input->post('city'),
                            'nationality' => $this->input->post('nationality'),
                            'gender' => $this->input->post('gender'),
                            'ip_address' => $this->input->ip_address(),
                            'dated' => $current_date
    );


    if (!empty($_FILES['cv_file']['name'])){

        //$verification_code = md5(time());

        $extention = get_file_extension($_FILES['cv_file']['name']);
        $allowed_types = array('doc','docx','pdf','rtf','jpg','txt');

        if(!in_array($extention,$allowed_types)){
            $data['cpt_code'] = create_ml_captcha();
            $data['msg'] = 'This file type is not allowed.';
            $this->load->view('jobseeker_signup_view',$data);
            return; 
        }

        $seeker_id = $this->job_seekers_model->add_job_seekers($job_seeker_array);
        $resume_array = array();
        $real_path = realpath(APPPATH . '../public/uploads/candidate/resumes/');
        $config['upload_path'] = $real_path;
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'doc|docx|pdf|rtf|jpg|txt';
        $config['overwrite'] = true;
        $config['max_size'] = 6000;
        $config['file_name'] = replace_string(' ','-',strtolower($this->input->post('full_name'))).'-'.$seeker_id;
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('cv_file')){
            $this->job_seekers_model->delete_job_seeker($seeker_id);
            $data['cpt_code'] = create_ml_captcha();
            $data['msg'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
            $this->load->view('jobseeker_signup_view',$data);
            return;
        }

        $resume = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());    
        $resume_file_name = $resume['upload_data']['file_name'];
        $resume_array = array(
                                'seeker_ID' => $seeker_id,
                                'file_name' => $resume_file_name,
                                'dated' => $current_date,
                                'is_uploaded_resume' => 'yes'

        );
    }
```

Comment: show your view page

Answer (score 0):

Remove this

```
if (empty($_FILES['cv_file']['name']))
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cv_file', 'Resume', 'required');
```